# React native level api 33

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradle, google-play

google play store have sent me a notification telling me that i have to use a higher level api destiny. but i dont know what i have to do. i have change in the file android/build.gradle buildToolsVersios and put this but it not working

`buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0" minSdkVersion = 21 compileSdkVersion = 33 targetSdkVersion = 33`

the info fetch by npx react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.22621
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 2.10 GB / 15.86 GB
Binaries:
Node: 18.17.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 9.6.7 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
Watchman: Not Found
SDKs:
Android SDK: Not Found
Windows SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: Not Found
Visual Studio: Not Found
Languages:
Java: 11.0.20
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found

```
react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
react-native: 0.64.4 => 0.64.4
react-native-windows: Not Found
```

npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found

if you need more info tell me

i have only change android/build.gradle file and its not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How to update Android Build Systems.

Sometimes, just upgrading SDK will break your code. So, we will spin the dependencies for the new environment and then upgrade your project.

1. Update your environment, installing the new SDK from Android Studio to run the newest version. Follow the tutorial here: [React-native environment install docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#installing-dependencies)
2. Upgrade your project, running one of three options:

- Running `npx react-native upgrade`. Or go version by version by manually setting the upgrade version: `npx react-native upgrade 0.65`
- Manually setting up the changes using this upgrade helper: [Upgrade Helper Website](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/)
- Spinning up a fresh project on an external folder, an then copying all the dependencies and source to the new project.

You can also, run only step 1. And going into `build.grade` and forcing the `buildToolsVersion` variable. But it might bring new unexpected errors.

Comment: i already do step1, on the step 2 i have execute the upgrade command but dosent work. i also use upgrade helper and i updated manualy to the version 0.69 but the proyect brakes so i just stop updating the proyect by this way.a im thinking of this making a new proyect and passing the code to that proyect but the project is big and i believe it is the worst way to do it. but i think i have to do it this way

Comment: When upgrading versions. It might give you easier fixes when going versions step by step. Try running `npx react-native upgrade 0.65` to do a single step ugprade. Commit and go on.

Comment: i try that too, telling which version to update also get an error